How to return the source document of retrieved nodes following llama index engine query?
My goal is rather straightforward: I want to return the document from which my nodes are derived for my RAG application. I want to do this so I can know which document is being most frequently referenced which can help me better evaluate my application. It looks like Langchain already has a functionality like this so i cannot imagine llama index does not support this ability. If anyone can help show me what method or technique can be used to achieve this that would be amazing!
The code below is some boilerplate code that uses Trulens and a prebuilt llama index sentence window engine to query some evaluation questions.
## build the index
sentence_index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
                self.documents, service_context=self.sentence_context
            )


# build engine
sentence_window_1 = sentence_window.build_sentence_window_index(save_dir='./indexes/content_sw_1')
sentence_window_engine_1 = sentence_window.get_sentence_window_query_engine(sentence_window_1)




from trulens_eval import Tru
tru = Tru()

tru.reset_database()

from utils import get_prebuilt_trulens_recorder
tru_recorder = get_prebuilt_trulens_recorder(sentence_window_engine_1, app_id='Direct Query Engine 2')

source_nodes = []
with tru_recorder as recording:
    for question in eval_questions:
        response = sentence_window_engine_1.query(question) # query with the engine
        source_nodes.append(response.source_nodes) # this returns the specific sentence nodes, I simply want the document from which the node was derived

records, feedback = tru.get_records_and_feedback(app_ids = [])

The records variable is then a dataframe that returns important evaluation information but I don't seem to find the original document from which the source nodes were derived.
